# Three/four-level entity relationship: Gallery/Exhibit/Painting/ExhibitPaintingDetail

Tags: next.js, foreign-keys, many-to-many, entity, typeorm

ERD for tables involved here is at https://4l3c78.axshare.com/#g=1&p=data

This is a nextjs/typeorm project. How are the relationships in the entities Exhibit, Painting, ExhibitPaintingDetail? The Postgres tables include foreign keys from Painting and Exhibit to ExhibitPaintingDetail.

Exhibit entity:

```
  @ManyToOne(() => Gallery, (gallery) => gallery.exhibits)
  gallery: Gallery;

  @ManyToMany(() => Painting, (painting) => painting.exhibits)
  @JoinTable({ name: "exhibit_paintings" }) // Specify the name of the junction table
  paintings?: Painting[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
    (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.exhibitId
  )
  exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];
```

The Painting entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.paintings)
  @JoinTable({ name: "exhibit_paintings" }) // Specify the name of the junction table
  exhibits: Exhibit[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Person, (person) => person.paintings)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "artistId" })
  person: Promise<Person>;
  exhibitRelations: any;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
    (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.paintingId
  )
  exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];
```

The ExhibitPaintingDetail table:

```
  @PrimaryColumn()
  exhibitId: number;
  @PrimaryColumn()
  paintingId: number;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "exhibitId" })
  exhibit: Exhibit;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Painting, (painting) => painting.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "paintingId" })
  painting: Painting;

  @OneToOne(() => ExhibitPaintings, (exhibitPaintings) => exhibitPaintings.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "exhibitpaintingId" })
  exhibitPaintings: ExhibitPaintings;
```

nextjs is reporting this error from the ExhibitPaintingDetail entity wherever:

```
Error: Cannot access 'Exhibit' before initialization
```

on the

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text.

Comment: What does "How are the relationships in the entities" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.  Debug questions require a [mre]. This post ends with a couple of unconnected words. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the entities that now work 100% of the time in localhost dev and 90% of the time on vercel production:

Exhibit:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToOne,
  //ManyToMany,
  //OneToOne,
  //JoinTable,
  OneToMany,
  JoinColumn,
  //Relation,
} from "typeorm";
//import * as typeorm from "typeorm";
import { Gallery } from "./Gallery";
//import { Painting } from "./Painting";
import { ExhibitPaintingDetail } from "./ExhibitPaintingDetail";

@Entity("exhibit")
export class Exhibit {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isEnabled?: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  startDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  endDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  dropOffDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  pickUpDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  galleryId: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  note: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  decisionDate?: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  website: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Gallery, (gallery) => gallery.exhibits, {})
  @JoinColumn({ name: "galleryId" })
  gallery: Promise<Gallery>;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
    (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.exhibit
  )
  exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];
}
```

Painting:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToMany,
  JoinTable,
  OneToMany,
} from "typeorm";
import { Exhibit } from "./Exhibit";
import { Person } from "./Person";
import { ExhibitPaintingDetail } from "./ExhibitPaintingDetail";
import { Tag } from "./Tag";
import { dateTimeRangeList } from "aws-sdk/clients/health";

@Entity("painting")
export class Painting {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  picture: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column("int")
  artistId: number;

  @Column("int")
  month: number;

  @Column()
  year: number;

  @Column()
  media: string;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @Column()
  width: number;

  @Column()
  height: number;

  @Column()
  sold: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  depth: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  note: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  api_id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  permalink: string;

  @Column("timestamp without time zone", { nullable: true })
  timestamp: Date;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
    (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.painting
  )
  exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Tag, (tag) => tag.paintings)
  @JoinTable({
    name: "tagpaintings", // name of the join table
    joinColumn: {
      name: "paintingid", // name of the column in the join table that references the Painting entity
      referencedColumnName: "id", // name of the id column in the Painting entity
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: "tagid", // name of the column in the join table that references the Tag entity
      referencedColumnName: "id", // name of the id column in the Tag entity
    },
  })
  tags: Tag[];
}
```

ExhibitPaintingDetail:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
} from "typeorm";
import { Exhibit } from "./Exhibit";
import { Painting } from "./Painting";

@Entity("exhibitpaintingdetail")
export class ExhibitPaintingDetail {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  exhibitpaintingid: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  submissiondate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  exhibitpaintingprice: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  status: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  outcome: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  note: string;

  // @Column()
  // exhibitid: number;

  // @Column()
  // paintingid: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "exhibitid" })
  exhibit: any;

  @ManyToOne(() => Painting, (painting) => painting.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "paintingid" })
  painting: any;
}
```